# Get selected option from fieldset

Tags: jquery, fieldset

This is causing me a lot of grief, and I'm almost positive it's something stupid.

Why is this returning undefined instead of "Test"?

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SXGTC/)

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <select class="list">
        <option selected="selected">Test</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('.fieldset').children('select.list option:selected').val());
</script>
```

Comment: `option:selected` is not a child of `.fieldset` so you can't make it part of the `children` selector. Either specify the list before calling `.children` or don't use the children method at all: `alert($('select.list>option:selected', '.fieldset').val());` this also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to use `find` instead of `children`.

`children` gives you the *immediate* descendants of your selector, i.e. only one level down. `find` searches all descendants. Otherwise, you were spot on!

(Keep in mind that if you have more than one `select` in your `fieldset`, your current selector will get them all at once. If this is not what you want, use something that gets the `select` you want specifically; in your example it would be `$('.list').children('select.list option:selected').val()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
alert($('.fieldset').children().val());
```

jsFiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SXGTC/6/)

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

`select.list` is a direct child of `.fieldset` but the `option` is not.

The `children` selector should specify the selector matching direct children of the `.fieldset` which the options are not as they are children of the list instead.

The [**children**](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method is not recursive and only looks for a match within the direct children/descendants not within the children of the children.

You can make the `select.list` selector part of your initial `selector` and then the children will be the `options` alright. Similar to this:

```
alert($('.fieldset select.list').children('option:selected').val());
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SbHpX/) - Corrected selector

---

In addition you can also get away with not using the children method at all like this:

```
alert($('.fieldset select.list>option:selected').val());
```

Or like this:

```
alert($('select.list>option:selected', '.fieldset').val());
```

There is many ways of doing it off course.

Comment: I added a few more alternatives, main thing is that the `children` selector must specify a selector to match elements which are direct descendants of the `.fieldset` in your example. Aside from that, there is plenty of ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('.fieldset select.list option:selected').val());
```